# How to mock serializer in django testing?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-rest-framework, pytest

So i was testing a rest api method in with we are returning json formatted serializer.data but when we tried to make testcases for this object we couldn't able to mock serializer properly.

---

##### views.py

```
data = {Something in jason format}
serializer = ClassName1(data=data)
serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)

rec_data = {Something in json format}
rec_serializer = ClassName2(data=rec_data)
rec_serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
return Response({'key01':serializer.data, 'key02':rec_serializer.data})
```

---

##### test_views.py

---

```
@mock.patch('myapp.serializers.ClassName1.data')
@mock.patch('myapp.serializers.ClassName2.data')
@mock.patch('myapp.serializers.ClassName1.is_valid')
@mock.patch('myapp.serializers.ClassName2.is_valid')
def test_serializer(TestCase, mock_c2_isvalid, mock_c1_isvalid, mock_c2_data, mock_c1_data):
    url = reverse('view-name')
    mock_c2_data.return_value = {dummy json data}
    mock_c1_data.return_value = {dummy json data}
    req = RequestFactory().get(url)
    response = views.Class.as_view()(req)
    self.assertEquals(response.status_code, 200)
```

above test case is working but we have to patch two times for one serializer if there is any way to mock the serializer object if self and use that to return value for some method.

let me know if there is another better way to mock serializer.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
@mock.patch('myapp.serializers.ClassName1', **{
   'return_value': {
      'data': {dummy json data},
      'is_valid': True,
   }
})
```